# How can I address traffic decline using SEO strategies after the Helpful Content Update (HCU)

Tags: google, web-development, content, reputation

Following the recent Helpful Content Update (HCU) in late 2023, my website has experienced a significant drop in traffic.

I'm interested in knowledge relating to the HCU update made in about September. For example, I've gleaned that Google is shifting toward highlighting user-based content such as forums such as Reddit and Quora.

Are there specific, proven SEO strategies that have been effective in counteracting the impact of the HCU on website traffic, according to recent studies or data?

Comment: I suggest you read https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google and other posts in the forum regarding content.  This post is very old, but the priority of having valuable content is still king.  I'm not saying your content isn't good, but I would start there anyway.